# Const-correctness semantics in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

For fun and profit™, I'm writing a trie class in C++ (using the C++11 standard.)

My `trie<T>` has an iterator, `trie<T>::iterator`.  (They're all actually *functionally* `const_iterator`s, because you cannot modify a trie's `value_type`.)  The iterator's class declaration looks partially like this:

```
template<typename T>
class trie<T>::iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T> {
    friend class trie<T>;
    struct state {
        state(const trie<T>* const node, const typename std::vector<std::pair<typename T::value_type, std::unique_ptr<trie<T>>>>::const_iterator& node_map_it ) :
            node{node}, node_map_it{node_map_it} {}
// This pointer is to const data:
        const trie<T>* node;
        typename std::vector<std::pair<typename T::value_type, std::unique_ptr<trie<T>>>>::const_iterator node_map_it;
    };
public:
    typedef const T value_type;
    iterator() =default;
    iterator(const trie<T>* node) {
        parents.emplace(node, node->children.cbegin());
            // ...
    }
    // ...
private:
    std::stack<state> parents;
    // ...
};
```

Notice that the `node` pointer is declared `const`.  This is because (in my mind) the iterator should not be modifying the node that it points to; it is just an iterator.

Now, elsewhere in my main `trie<T>` class, I have an erase function that has a common STL signature--it takes an `iterator` to data to erase (and returns an `iterator` to the next object).

```
template<typename T>
typename trie<T>::iterator trie<T>::erase(const_iterator it)
{
    // ...

    // Cannot modify a const object!
    it.parents.top().node->is_leaf = false;

    // ...
}
```

The compiler complains because the `node` pointer is read-only!  The `erase` function definitely should modify the trie that the iterator points to, even though the iterator shouldn't.

So, I have two questions:

1. **Should `iterator`'s constructors be public?**  `trie<T>` has the necessary `begin()` and `end()` members, and of course `trie<T>::iterator` and `trie<T>` are mutual friends, but I don't know what the convention is.  Making them private would solve a lot of the angst I'm having about removing the `const` "promise" from the iterator's constructor.
2. **What are the correct `const` semantics/conventions regarding the iterator and its `node` pointer here?**  Nobody has ever explained this to me, and I can't find any tutorials or articles on the Web.  This is probably the more important question, but it does require a good deal of planning and proper implementation.  I suppose it could be circumvented by just implementing 1, but it's the *principle* of the thing!

Comment: What you implemented is a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Yes.  A trie splits an array-like object into a tree, so that "horse" and "horses" (for example) share the base string "horse".  In such a structure, the data is not directly mutable.

Comment: That's the sort of problems than can be solved with `friend`s: Give a const to the user, give a non-const to your `friend class trie`.

Comment: @rici: the thing is, you *can* use a `const_iterator` to modify the container, but only indirectly via a non-const function on the container such as `container::erase(const_iterator)`. The questioner therefore is using a pointer-to-const to prevent the iterator modifying directly in its own member functions (which after all is exactly what `const` is for). The question, then, is how the container should use the `const_iterator` to get a non-const pointer to the position in the container where it's supposed to make the modification.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Good point. I'd somehow completely missed the fact that `erase` takes a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) All iterators are required to be copy-constructible. Your iterator is Bi-directional, hence is also required to be default-constructible (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), although I don't know why. So the default constructor needs to be public but you can do what you like with the `const trie<T>*` one. I would think it should be private, since the purpose of this class is to provide the user with an iterator over the trie, and so its public interface should be only that of an iterator of the appropriate category. No need for any extra public constructors.

2) `erase` is a non-const function. The only iterators you can validly pass to it are iterators that refer to the same trie that the function is called on, which means (I think, although I'm not quite certain I've followed your design) the whole hierarchy of parents are non-const objects. So I suspect this is one of those cases where you can `const_cast<trie<T>*>(it.parents.top().node)`. The *iterator* isn't allowed to use it to modify the trie, which is why you want it to hold a pointer-to-const. But when you hold a non-const pointer to the trie, namely `this`, you are allowed to modify any part of it you like, and the iterator is just giving you the position to start modifying from.

There might be some more general principle of const-safety you can draw here. One possible case in `container::erase(const_iterator)` functions is that the `const container*` you'd get from the iterator is equal to `this`. In that case the `const_cast` is certainly both safe and legitimate (as well as unnecessary, because you can just use `this`, but that's beside the point of whether it's const-correct or not). In your container it is not (in general) equal to `this`, it points to one of the several `trie` objects that together make up the hierarchical container that `this` is part of. The good news is, that whole container is logically const or logically non-const together, hence the `const_cast` is just as safe and legitimate as if it were all one object. But a bit harder to prove correct, because you have to make sure that in your design the whole hierarchical container genuinely does, as I've assumed, share non-constness.

Comment: Many standard algorithms are more natural when you can define a iterator variable with no initial value.  This requires either default-initialization or other solutions that are uglier, like fake values, dynamic allocation or boost::optional-like hacks.

Comment: You're correct about the design...  I'm very reluctant to `const_cast<>` away the `const`-ness.  However, if the constructor that takes a pointer is private, then I wouldn't mind (quite as much) making the iterator's pointer non-const.  The stack is necessary for walking up and down the trie, because of the design of this particular one.

Comment: @BatchyX: yes, that's what I was silently guessing to myself must be the case, but I can't for the moment think of a standard algorithm off the top of my head whose obvious implementation calls for an uninitialized iterator. That said, if the concepts are to support the old "define everything at the top of the function" coding style, then of course what you say is right, if you can't default-construct then you'd have to assign whatever arbitrary value of the type you have lying around (quite possibly a `start` or `finish` parameter), knowing you'll never use the value.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: like Adam says, if your iterator has a pointer-to-non-const then you have to do an even *more* dubious `const_cast` in `trie<T>::begin() const` and `trie<T>::cbegin() const`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't follow entirely.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: Suppose you go ahead and make it a pointer-to-non-const. Soon you'll be ready to implement `trie<T>::const_iterator begin() const`. `trie<T>::const_iterator` has a data member that's a `trie<T>*`. Where are you going to get a value for that data member, given that within `begin() const`, `this` has type `const trie<T>*`?

Comment: Oh.  Good point.  Somewhere I think I saw how you could templatize an iterator so that a `const_iterator` had a `const` pointer, and the non-const one didn't.  Of course, I failed to bookmark it.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: you *could* do that template, but it wouldn't help you because `trie::erase` takes a `const_iterator`. So if it's going to read a pointer out of the iterator without casting it, then that pointer needs to be to non-const in `const_iterator` as well as in `iterator`. In C++03, container `erase` functions did only accept `iterator`, possibly because at some point in the past Stepanov or someone else involved in designing and implementing the container interface, hit exactly this problem you have, and decided to avoid it instead of solving it ;-)

Comment: Haha, I think that last comment helps me wrap my head around the issue the most.

Comment: Thanks for the update, very good opinion.  You have assumed correct.  I like either option:  `const_cast<>`ing away the `const`ness (because as you mentioned, this cast will only happen when the data structure is mutable *anyway*, or simply making the iterator's pointer non-`const`, because the iterator as a logical unit implements const-ness.

Answer (score 1):

Non-`const` methods of `trie` that wish to modify what a `const_iterator` points to (what it points to should be within `this` instance of `trie`) should just `const_cast` as needed. You know this is a safe and defined cast because if someone managed to call a non-`const` instance of this `trie`, then this instance of `trie` itself is not `const`.*

Alternatively you could do the opposite and hold non-`const` pointer(s) to the `trie` within the `const_iterator`, which will require a `const_cast` upon construction. This is safe for the same reason, above. The `const_iterator` methods will only provide `const` access, so the user can't mutate the part(s) of `trie` that the iterator points to. And if a `const_iterator` needs to be mutated in a non-`const` `trie` method it's okay because the `trie` must not have been `const` in the first place.*

The premise of the safety of `const_cast`ing here is that it is safe to hold and use a non-`const` pointer to a `const` object so long as you do not mutate that object. And it is safe to turn a cast away the `const`ness of a pointer which points to something which wasn't originally declared as `const`.

*Yes, the caller of the non-`const` `trie` method might have `const_cast`ed in an undefined way; but in that case the burdon of causing undefined behavior is on their head, not `trie`s.

Comment: This means you can't create an iterator on a `const trie<T>`.

Comment: @Adam, I think that I can templatize the trie<T> further to allow that.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty templates won't help. You can't assign a const pointer to a non-const pointer (without a const_cast, obviously, but what you have here shouldn't require one).

Comment: @Adam You could `const_cast` it like you said, and that should be safe because you'll never call a non-`const` method on a `const trie`, and you can only get `const` access through the iterator, even though it internally holds it as non-`const`. I understand your concern though, it sounds dirty.

Comment: @Dave `erase` is not a const method and your scheme would allow that.

Comment: @Adam Furthering my last thought - it would also be 'safe' to `const_cast` `node` in `erase` and other non-`const` methods.

Comment: @Dave yes, but ONLY if it's an `iterator`, not a `const_iterator`. That's how it's often done to avoid having to rewrite the entire class. `erase`has no business in a `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Adam What would it allow incorrectly? My thoughts here about safety are on the premise that it's safe to have non-`const` access to something that is `const` as long as you don't mutate it. The user of the iterator can't mutate what the iterator points to because they only have `const` access, and the `trie` itself can mutate what the `iterator` points to when you are calling a non-`const` method because if you _can_ call a non-`const` method on `trie` then `trie` itself is not `const`.

Comment: Does a `const_iterator` imply that the whole *structure* it points to is const, or that only the elements *within* the structure are const?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Neither. It implies that you have `const` _access_ to what it points to.

Comment: Obviously the `const_iterator` itself cannot be const otherwise you wouldn't be able to increment it. But all references to the original collection are const.

Comment: The data structure *itself* can be modified, but the individual elements cannot.  Have I described a `const_iterator` or an `iterator`?

Comment: @Dave I missed the part that `erase` is part of `trie` and not `iterator::erase`. That iterator can be const as long as all references to the trie are through other, non-const, references.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty which "structure"? The trie or the iterator?

Comment: The trie can be modified; individual elements (strings) cannot, because strings are broken into letters in the trie.  Sorry for the confusion, @Adam.

Comment: If the trie can be modified in any way (data or structure) *through* the iterator then it's an `iterator`. It's fine for an `iterator` to return a const reference to the string, though. If the only purpose of the iterator is to read the trie and use other non-const functions to make any changes then the iterator can be a `const_iterator`. At least in c++11 as Steve said.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Should `iterator`'s constructors be public?**

At least the copy constructor, yes. Have a look at this chart that describes the traits each type of iterator should have:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

All iterator types should be *copy-constructible, copy-assignable and destructible*, so that means they need public copy constructors. Some iterators, for example the [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/) should also be *default constructible* so the default constructor should be public as well.

1. **What are the correct `const` semantics/conventions regarding the iterator and its `node` pointer here?**

If you want to have an `erase` then you don't really have a `const_iterator`, you have a regular `iterator`. The difference between the two is that if you have a `const` `trie` object then you can only get a `const_iterator` out of it because you're not allowed to modify it in any way.

You can notice this in the STL containers. They tend to have both:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const;
```

What usually happens is that you implement a `const_iterator` then:

```
class iterator : public const_iterator {...};
```

which implements the one or two non-const functions. This probably means just `erase` for you, since your `operator*` is going to stay const.

Comment: Why must the `RandomAccessIterator` be default constructible?  Is that just one of the class's specifications?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty yes it is specified (that RandomAccessIterator text is actually a link to the spec).

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I think the logic is that a RandomAccessIterator is basically supposed to act like a pointer, and pointers can be default constructed.

Comment: @Adam: it's not a link to "the spec", it's a link to some website that's paraphrasing the standard. Same goes for my link, of course.

Comment: @Adam: I have a more constructive remark, on "If you want to have an erase then you don't really have a const_iterator, you have a regular iterator". This is changed in C++11, the `erase()` functions of containers now take `const_iterator`. I believe the logic is that you might want to perform some iterator-based algorithm that is not permitted to modify the container (hence takes `const_iterators`) in order to to work out a position in the container. Then provided you have a non-const reference to the container yourself, you're entitled to use it to modify the container without a nasty cast.

Comment: @SteveJessop sure, as long as you don't use the iterator itself to do the erase. If you have a non-const reference, then no problem. I think I missed the part that `erase` is a member of `trie` and not of `iterator`. I was thinking `iterator::erase`.

Comment: @Adam: ok. As far as I can tell there is no `iterator::erase` in this design, so I thought you were talking about `trie::erase`.