# assigning a pointer to const to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

According to a book I'm reading:

> we can use a pointer to const to point to a nonconst object:

I tried this:

```
int i = 42;
int *p1 = &i;
const int *const p3 = 0;
p1 = p3; //error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

Why is this? I tried this with ints and it worked. This is the from the book:

```
int i = 42;
const int ci = i;
int j = ci;
```

I thought pointers are objects as well?

Comment: The line from the book is `const int *p1 = &i;`. The last line violates constness.

Comment: Please see my edit, I posted the wrong code earlier

Comment: You're doing the opposite of what the quote says.

Comment: You didn't try the same thing with ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to `const` is about privileges, not the fundamental type of the pointed-to object.

Essentially, with an `int const *` (which is the same as `const int*`), you can look at the `int` (which may or may not be `const` itself), but you can't change it.  Casting a non-`const` pointer to a `const` one allows you to pass a pointer to your own data to a function and not worry that the function might modify it, even though you still can.

To preserve the above dynamic, you can't "get rid" of `const`ness by assigning to another pointer.*  That's what your error is saying.  That is,

```
const int * constPtr;
int * nonconstPtr;

*nonconstPtr = 42;      // legal
constPtr = nonconstPtr; // legal

*constPtr = 42;         // illegal!
nonconstPtr = constPtr; // illegal!
```

<sub>* You actually *can* cast away `const`ness with `const_cast<>`.  And there are [correct uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527507) of the operation.  But it is usually very wrong, and you should very probably avoid it.</sub>

Comment: What about this example:
    int i = 42;
    const int ci = i;
    int j = ci;
It is said in the book that int j = ci; coppies the value of ci and this object does not have a connection to the original. Isn't it the same in pointers?

Comment: Ah, that's different.  A `const int*` is totally unrelated to a `int* const`.  The first is a pointer to a constant integer (which is what I talked about in the answer).  The second is a constant pointer to an integer, which is just a read-only pointer that points to a read-write integer.  So yes, it is the same with pointers.  You just have to be careful with the types.

Comment: Do you mean, if we say "const int *i = 42;", only the value 42 is constant but the pointer is not? And since "int *const i" is a const pointer, you can't assign it into a normal pointer because const pointer can only be assigned in a const pointer also?

Comment: If you have `const int *i` you are declaring a pointer to a constant integer.  Assigning the pointer to 42 is legal but very likely to crash, since 42 is probably not an address you are allowed to read or write.  You probably mean `const int *i; *i = 42;`, which *is* disallowed, because `i` points to a constant integer.  You are correct regarding `const int * const` types.  In that case, both the pointer and the pointee are `const`.

Comment: Thanks! Got it! Just to make it worked I changed the code to this:
    const int i = 42;
    const int * p1 = &i;
    int *const p3 = 0;
    p1 = p3;
Pointers are so confusing :))

Comment: Indeed they are, and they're what C is built on.  If you can figure out types and pointers, you have about 75% of the language licked.  Good luck!

Comment: Regarding const int *i, I actually mean like this: const int j = 6; const int *i = &j; (the and sign before j doesn't want to appear). Thanks again :))